# Facebook share from mobile without being redirected to facebook.com

Tags: ios, facebook, authentication, youtube, share

I come up to you for a simple question : 
I have a simple webpage, with a share button at the bottom (or shareDialog, I think it doesn't matter). 
I would like people to be able to share this webpage. On a desktop, it works perfectly because most of the time people are already authenticated to facebook.com.

However, on mobile device they're most of the time authenticated with the facebook native app (or in IOS, there is a way to set a facebook account in settings), and not with the facebook regular website.
This means that when they'll try to share my webpage, they'll be redirected to facebook.com to authenticate ! It's a problem because I suppose they won't do it most of the time.

Well, if I use the youtube native app for example, I can share videos without being redirected to facebook.com, I suppose because native youtube app is allowed to get the facebook authentication directly from the native FB app ? I suppose so, because if I try to share content from youtube.com on my phone, I am redirected to facebook.com as well !

So, is there a way for people to share content from a webpage without being redirected, and using native authentication instead ?

Thanks for your help !
Quentin

Comment: that´s not possible for websites, it only depends on the browser on your device and if you are logged in on facebook there.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by using SLComposeViewController. 
If the user is signed in the facebook from settings than it will post the URL without opening FB app.

```
SLComposeViewController *controllerSLC = [SLComposeViewControlle composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook];
[controllerSLC setInitialText:@"First post from my iPhone app"];
[controllerSLC addURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.appcoda.com"]];
[controllerSLC addImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"test.jpg"]];
[self presentViewController:controllerSLC animated:YES completion:Nil];
```